# What's this log messages in logcat?

Tags: android, logcat

When I build my app in emulator this log message is coming up non-stop. I don't know what is causing this, should I be worried about it or can simply ignore it and release my code?

> 23822-22026/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=40, operation=LogOperation
>       OperationException[Status{statusCode=Log from GMA_SDK dropped because of storage full, resolution=null}]
>           at pgd.a(:com.google.android.gms@14570022@14.5.70 (040700-217905028):109)
>           at xqo.run(:com.google.android.gms@14570022@14.5.70 (040700-217905028):27)
>           at beix.run(:com.google.android.gms@14570022@14.5.70 (040700-217905028):2)
>           at qtz.run(:com.google.android.gms@14570022@14.5.70 (040700-217905028):19)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>           at rab.run(Unknown Source:7)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: You should filter the logs you want to see, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSVq5.png).

Comment: that's coming from play services Ad sdk

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the complete question. No, you should not be worried about these logs unless you're getting an exception causing your application to stop unexpectedly, otherwise you're good to release the app.